# Showing AdMob ad not every time

Tags: ios, swift

How can I show an AdMob ad not every single time by clicking a button? Is there a possibility to set after how many clicks or how much time the ad should be shown?

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var BannerView: GADBannerView!

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3581855984")
        let request2 = GADRequest()
        interstitial.loadRequest(request2)

        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        BannerView.delegate = self
        BannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/2613153588"
        BannerView.rootViewController = self
        BannerView.loadRequest(request)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createAD() -> GADInterstitial{
        let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3581855984")
        interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }

    @IBAction func ShowAD(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (interstitial.isReady){

            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            interstitial = createAD()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a probability mechanism, extract a random number from 1 to 100.
If number is under a certain threshold, show the ad otherwise no.
For example is threshold is 30, you 30% of probability to show the ad.
Something like this:

```js
func shouldShowAd(chance: Int ) -> Bool {

    //extract number from 0 to 100
    //arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1))
    let extracted = arc4random_uniform(101)

    return chance >= Int(extracted)
}

// set the threshold from 0 (never show ads) to 100 (always show ads)
// for example a chance of 40 is 40% of probability of showing ads

@IBAction func ShowAD(sender: AnyObject) {
    if shouldShowAd(chance: 40) {
        if (interstitial.isReady){
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            interstitial = createAD()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example that fits for my code please?

Comment: i will post an example editing original answer

Comment: could you please give me an example with the code above I always gets errors...

Comment: answer edited with your code